# Yet another Google Android Maps API v2 authentication issue

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I had a working Google maps API v2 for Android example application that worked perfectly until I initialized a git repository in it's directory.
I have since then erased the entire project, all references to it in the Google cloud control, and started a new project.
The problem I'm facing now is an authentication issue:
*11-07 10:44:05.445: E/Google Maps Android API(3640): Ensure that the following correspond to what is in the API Console: Package Name: [package name], API Key: [key], Certificate Fingerprint: [fingerprint]*
I already tried with no avail:
1. Triple check API key and correct
2. Erase the entire project, disable Google maps API v2 for Android, enable it again and recreate the project
3. Add permissions for MAPS_RECEIVE
4. Cleaning, removing, and re-installing the release package

Really stumped by this one...
Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.mypackage"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.mycompany.mypackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.mycompany.mypackage.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="[My Key]" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.mycompany.canipark.MapExample"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here is the code:

```
package com.mycompany.mypackage;

import com.mycompany.mypackage.R;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MapExample extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gmaps);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.gmaps, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:mapType="normal" />
```

And the Google cloud console:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSx9N.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sNbm.jpg

Comment: did you use this `com.mycompany.mypackage` in google api console

Comment: @Raghunandan If you mean if I registered this package with the SHA-1 key, then yes

Comment: Tell me, How you create SHA-1 key??? I have this issue just because of SHA-1 keys.

Comment: @AhmadRaza The easiest way I found was exporting the package from eclipse. You'll get the MD5 and SHA-1 in the summary

Comment: Do you have only one API Key? Or one for the exported APK and one for the debug APK? Do you see the erro when debuggin? Did you follow the steps in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#display_your_apps_certificate_information the generate the SHA-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand this..
I waited two days, and suddenly everything's working again. I didn't change a single line of code.

Wish Google will add a meaningful error other than Authorization failure when it does...
Thanks guys for your help!

Answer (score 2):

ID of your package is **com.mycompany.canipark**, but in [console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sNbm.jpg)  **com.mycompany**

Also, try to write

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

In AndroidManifest.xml in `<application>` section

Comment: also make sure you put the right value in the metadata   <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="[My Key]" />

Comment: I was trying to hide the actual package name, guess I forgot to remove it from the activity name (-;
The package name is consistent throughout the console and the application references